# Estimate missing points in a list of points

Tags: python, interpolation, point

I'm generating a list of (x,y) coordinates from detecting a ball's flight in a video. The problem I have is for a few frames in the middle of the video the ball can't be detected, for these frames the list appends (-1,-1).
Is there a way to estimate the true (x,y) coordinates of the ball for these points?

Eg tracked points list being:

```
pointList = [(60, 40), (55, 42), (53, 43), (-1, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, -1), (35, 55), (30, 60)]
```

Then returning an estimate of what the 3 (-1,-1) missing coordinates would be with context to the sourounding points (preserving the curve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a ball then theoretically it should have a parabolic path, you could try and fit a curve ignoring the (-1, -1) and then replace the missing values.

Something like...

```
import numpy as np

pointList = [(60, 40), (55, 42), (53, 43), (-1, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, -1), (35, 55), (30, 60)]

x, y = list(zip(*[(x, y) for (x, y) in pointList if x>0]))

fit = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
polynome = np.poly1d(fit)

# call your polynome for missing data, e.g.
missing = (55 - i*(55-35)/4 for i in range(3))
print([(m, polynome(m)) for m in missing])
```

giving ...

```
[(55.0, 41.971982486554325), (50.0, 44.426515896714186), (45.0, 47.44514924300471)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scipys spline` to interpolate the missing values:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev
pointList = [(60, 40), (55, 42), (53, 43),
             (-1, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, -1), 
             (35, 55), (30, 60)]

# Remove the missing values
pointList = np.array(pointList)
pointList = pointList[pointList[:, 0] != -1, :]

def spline(x, n, k=2):
    tck = splprep(x.T, s=0, k=k)[0]
    u = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n)
    return np.column_stack(splev(x=u, tck=tck))

# Interpolate the points with a quadratic spline at 100 points
pointList_interpolated = spline(pointList, n=100, k=2)

plt.plot(*pointList.T, c='r', ls='', marker='o', zorder=10)
plt.plot(*pointList_interpolated.T, c='b')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If camera is not moving - just the ball and you ignore the wind, then trajectory is parabolic. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory#Uniform_gravity,_neither_drag_nor_wind

In this case fit quadratic function to points which you know and you will get missing ones. Set also error of boundary points in the vicinity of unknown area (point 53,43 and 35, 55) to be 0 or close to 0 (no-error, big weight in interpolation) when fitting so your interpolation will go through these points.

There are some libraries for polynomial fit. E.g. *numpy.polyfit*:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html